# Does a class implementing an interface take into account the types in the interface?

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain to me why with typescript and Webstorm the following does not give an error:

```
interface IABC {

    var1: boolean;
}

class ABC implements IABC {
    var1;
    constructor() {
    }
    clear= (): void => {
        this.var1 = 999;
    };
}
```

producing:

```
var ABC = (function () {
    function ABC() {
        var _this = this;
        this.clear = function () {
            _this.var1 = 999;
        };
    }
    return ABC;
})();
```

Is it something just with Webstorm or is it normal that it would allow var1 to be assigned 999?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. What version of typescript are you using? Can you try to compile this with tsc? If tsc correctly fails to compile, please log a bug with Webstorm.  I have used TS with webstorm a bit and could not get noImplicitAny to work. Ended up just using the ts Watcher to compile ts and only used Webstorm for intellisense. It didn't seem to give me errors for obvious things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing the same on the playground.
I think it is because without type annotation it is typed as `any`, if you make `var1` a number it doesn't compile with the following message

> Class 'ABC' incorrectly implements interface 'IABC':
>    Types of property 'var1' are incompatible: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

So I think because it doesn't have typeinfo it is typed as `any` and therefore everything is allowed.

Note if you enable `--noImplicitAny` it would have given you an error on the var1 declaration because it has implicit any in this case.